# Installing ROracle

Tags: r, oracle, roracle

I have downloaded the compiled ROracle package from the Oracle website. I have set my working directory with `setwd()`. Then I tried to install the package as follows:

```
install.packages("ROracle-1.3.2.zip", repos=NULL)
```

It failed and I got the following error message:

```
Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
  cannot open compressed file 'ROracle-1.3.2/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

I also tried from command line just in case:

```
R CMD INSTALL ROracle-1.3.2.zip
```

It also failed and I got the following error message:

```
* installing to library 'Z:/R/R-3.6.1/library'
Warning in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
  cannot open compressed file 'ROracle-1.3.2/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
  cannot open the connection
```

The DESCRIPTION file certainly exists in ROracle-1.3.2.zip. I opened it up and looked at - just a normal DESCRIPTION file.

I am using Windows 7.

How do I install ROracle?

Comment: I had the same issue. It looks like RORACLE still doesn't support R 3.6.1. When you download the package from R it states that the packages was configured for R 3.6.0. I am still working on finding a way to force it to work. I'll let you know if I get anywhere with it.

Comment: I've had the same issue with R 3.5.2 and ROracle-1.3.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to follow the following procedure:

1. Create a folder called "ROracle" and put the downloaded zip ROracle-1.3.2.zip in there
2. Unzip the .zip file in the folder. Now you have all the contents of the zip file (including the original zip file) in the ROracle folder that you created in step 1
3. Remove the original .zip file from the folder. Now the folder "ROracle" you created in step 1 only contains the **contents** of the original .zip file
4. Add the "ROracle" folder to a zip file called "ROracle.zip"

Got down into this solution by comparing hierarchy of earlier ROracle_1.3-1.zip -file which i got working well in earlier R version.

After following all these steps the outcome is that the DESCRIPTION file can be found in `ROracle.zip/ROracle/DESCRIPTION` instead of `ROracle-1.3.2.zip/DESCRIPTION`

With the newly zip-file from step 4 the installation is a quite straightforward.

```
setwd("THEPLACEWHERETHE ROracle.zip file is located)
install.packages('ROracle.zip', repos = NULL)
```

My `.Renviron` contains these lines if that matters

```
    # PATH="C:/Rtools/bin;C:/oracle/instantclient_19_5;$PATH"
    # OCI_LIB64 = C:/oracle/instantclient_19_5
    # BINPREF="C:/Rtools/mingw_$(WIN)/bin/"
```

OS is WIN10.
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12) -- "Dark and Stormy Night"
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
ROracle 1.3-2

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm no longer working on that project. However, here's what I did. Install the Oracle ODBC drivers and then used RODBC.

Comment: FYI.  The zip file ROracle1-4_Windows.zip (as downloaded from Oracle) contains the structure, but you must first rename the zip to ROracle.zip for the install to work.   You get "cannot open compressed file 'ROracle1.4-1_Windows/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'"  if you do not rename to ROracle.zip ( in R 4.3.2).