# How to install ROracle package to R version R4.1.0?

Tags: r, roracle

The current R version is 4.1.0.

And I cannot install ROracle to R due to ROracle was prepared for before 4.0.0 R versions.

I used all methods in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57195880/installing-roracle) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232917/how-to-install-roracle-package)

But I didn't succed.

Please, help.

Comment: @user438383 as soon as the error message in Russian I will translate you into English. 
`Error: package 'ROracle' was built before R 4.0.0: please reinstall it`

Comment: You can install it from sources of ROracle, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70748384/4121281)